# About demonstration of sum of powers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

In the book "250 problems in Elementary Number Theory", the problem 9 asks to prove that

$$ 1^3+2^3+\dots + n^3 \big\vert 3(1^5+2^5+\dots + n^5) $$

But in the demonstration (page 25 of Solutions) it says that by induction,

$$1^5+2^5+\dots + n^5= \frac{1}{12}n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$$

I know where comes from the three first factors, but I don't know where comes from the factor $2n^2+2n-1$. Can anyone help me understand it?

I adjoint the book:
http://www.isinj.com/usamo/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20(1970).pdf

Comment: it must be a polynomial of degree $5+1 = 6$ no matter what. Next, do you know mathematical induction?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us where you think the first factors come from, so we can figure out what sort of answer you are seeking. Probably best to write it as $$\frac{T_n^2(4T_n-1)}{3}$$ where $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ are the triangular numbers.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a proof by induction of OP's question about sums of powers.

Comment: @martycohen You realize the question at hand is not the probulem stated at the beginning, right?

Comment: @WillJagy I know induction, and I know that the degree of the polynomial of sums of powers of degree $n$ must be $n+1$, but I don't understand how he makes that affirmation without anything else more.

Comment: @martycohen , yes, I know that the initial problem is not the question, but I made the reference to point to the demonstration.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois, the authors claim the statement to be true by induction, not that they obtained it by induction. Also if $S_k$ is the sum of the $k$th powers of the first n numbers, then from knowing the expression for $S_1,\ldots, S_t$, you can get the expression for $S_{t+1}$ "by induction".

Comment: @Aravind How you can you obtain the next $S_i$ based on the $S_k$ ($k<i$)?

Comment: By the method of differences, eg: expand $(N+1)^6-N^6$, which is a degree 5 polynomial. Now sum it from 1 to $n$. The L.H.S. is $(n+1)^6-1$, the R.H.S. can be expressed in terms of $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_5$ and knowing the first four, you can find the fifth.